# Determine best possible Lipschitz constant

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, continuity

I'm slightly confused by a homework problem here...I've been given the function:

$ f(u) = log(u) $

With the bounds:

$ 2 \leq u \lt \infty $

Now I thought I understood what the Lipschitz Condition required, but that was a function of two variables, but here I only have $u$. Believe it or not, I'm not a math major and I'm confused as to how to proceed using the definition of the Lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $L$ the desired Lipschitz  constant then
$$\forall x,y\ge 2\quad |f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|$$
hence

$$\forall y\ge 2\quad\lim_{x\to y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=|f'(y)|=\frac1y\le L$$
hence we have
$$\frac12\le L$$
hence $L=\frac12$ is the best value of $L$ in the sense that if $ L<\frac12 $ the Lipschitz inequality is no longer true.

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting caught up in details, but isn't the fact that my function is only for $u$ a problem? I'd be able to do what you suggested if it were $f(x,y)$, why does this confuse me, what am I missing?

Comment: Calling the variable $u$ or $x$ or whatever doesn't change anything it's just a dummy variable.

Comment: Ok, so then if I wanted to check the continuity over a different domain, say change it to $ 0 \lt u \lt \infty$, I couldn't, correct?

Comment: We know that a Lipschitz function is a continuous function but in our case the function $\log$ isn't lipschitzian on the interval $(0,\infty)$ since it's derivative isn't bounded but we can overcome this problem: the function $\log $ is lipschitzian on every interval $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: In the language used then, I would have to say "log(u) is not LC over the domain $0 \lt u \lt \infty$, however, it is for any interval $[a,\infty]$ where $a \gt 0$" ?

Comment: Yes this is true!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the smallest $M$ such that for any two $x,y\in[2,\infty)$ you have
$$\vert \ln(x) -\ln(y)\vert \le M \vert x - y\vert.$$
The largest $M$ will be necessary where the derivative is the largest, which in this case is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so is greatest where the $x,y$ values are the smallest.

Set $y=2$ and look at $$\lim_{x\to 2^+} \frac{\ln x - \ln y}{x - y}.$$  This is one definition of the derivative at 2, i.e., the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.  This will be the largest value of $M$ you would need in your domain.

Comment: So since my function is only of $u$, I can still just take any two $x, y$ from this domain and apply the definition?

Comment: That's right.  $x$ and $y$ are variables in the domain, you can use any letters you like.  Some people would use $u_0$ and $u_1$, others $u$ and $v$, and while not advisable it's not entirely unacceptable to use Greek letters like $\nu$ and $\xi$.  The best idea is to use the symbols your instructor and textbook use.