# Understanding why an IVP has a solution, using uniqueness and existence theory

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, continuity

Given the existence and uniqueness theory:

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous over some region $D$, then there is a unique solution to the initial value problem (IVP):

$u'(t) = f(u,t), \hspace{5mm} u(0)=\eta$

at least up to time $T^*=min(t_1,t_0+a/S)$ where,

$ S = \max\limits_{(u,t)\in D} |{f(u,t)}|  $.

What I'd like to do (riffing off a previous question I asked, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695268/determine-best-possible-lipschitz-constant/695277?noredirect=1#comment1456971_695277)), is to use the E&U theorem to show that:

$u'(t) = log(u(t))$

$u(0) = 2$

Actually has a unique solution for any $t \geq 0$.

My strategy would be to show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous inside a domain that the solution never leaves, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(u,t)=\log u$ is $C^\infty$, and thus Lipschitz continuous, with respect to $u$, for $u>0$. Also, $f(2)=\log 2>0$, and $f(u)>0$ for $u\ge 2$. Thus, the solution of the IVP is strictly increasing, and is globally defined. (The last statement requires a bit more work.)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how the existence and uniqueness theorem is being applied? I feel like your answer is mostly common sense. Please feel free to include as many trivial details, as I need them!

Also, I'm getting really confused with all the $f$'s and $u$'s being interchanged, can you suggest any strategies to keep this straight in my head?